# Trying to get input field and button to align in center of div- jsfiddle

Tags: css

I have a div that I am trying to place an input field and submit button inside, center aligned, but I have been fooling with it and can't get it to work:

```
#headsearch {
position: relative;
float: center;
}
.form-wrapper {
width: 470px;
padding: 15px;
margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
background: #444;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.header_s { 
float: left;
height: 30px;
width: 230px; 
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 10px !important;
position: relative;
font-size: 1.2em !important;
}
.header_s_submit { 
float: left; 
height: 50px;
width: 60px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 3px;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form class="form-wrapper">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" class="header_s query noshadow" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" class="header_s_submit noshadow">Go</button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5g7Ux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your jsfiddle:

```
#headsearch {
    position: relative;
    /* float: center; there is no such thing as float:center; */
    text-align:center; /* add this */
}
.form-wrapper {
    width: 470px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.header_s { 
    display:inline-block; /* remove float, and make inline-block */
    height: 30px;
    width: 230px; 
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
}
.header_s_submit { 
    display:inline-block; /* remove float, and make inline-block */
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing is that the submit button is wrapping to its own line underneath, not floating to the right of the input field.

Comment: You control if the line breaks with the width of the container, in this case #headsearch and/or .form-wrapper. You can also try putting ```white-space: nowrap;``` in the css for those containers